# Multiple definition of `main' while bison output file compiling

Tags: c, parsing, bison

So I'm writing a bison (without lex) parser and now I want to read the input code from file and to write the output to another file.

Searching the stackoverflow for some time I found that this way should be good.
bison.y:

```
%{
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    extern FILE *yyin;

    int yylex() { return getc(stdin); }
    void yyerror(char *s) {
      fprintf (stderr, "%s\n", s);
    }
    int counter = 1;
    char filename2[10] = "dest.ll";
    FILE *f2;
%}
%name parse

%%

//grammars

%%

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (argc > 2)
      f2 = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    else
      f2 = fopen(filename2, "w");
    yyparse();

    return 0;
}
```

Then i compile it this way:

```
bison bison.y
cc -ly bison.tab.c
```

And here the result of cc-compilation:

```
/tmp/ccNqiuhW.o: In function `main':
bison.tab.c:(.text+0x960): multiple definition of `main'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/liby.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0x0): first defined here
/tmp/ccNqiuhW.o: In function `main':
bison.tab.c:(.text+0x98c): undefined reference to `yyin'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The output bison.tab.c file have only 1 main. Ofc int/void main doesn't matter. Can you teach me how to do it correctly?

P.S. By the way, I don't want to spam different posts, and have a little question here. How can I store the string (char *) in $$ in bison? For example, I want to generate a code string after I met the int grammar. I have this error and can't find the answer:

```
bison.y:94:8: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
 INTNUM: NUMBER | DIGIT INTNUM {$$ = "string"};

bison.y: In function ‘yyparse’:
bison.y:28:15: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 3 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
 PROGRAM: EXPRS { fprintf(f2, "%s: string here %d.\n", $$, counter++) };
```

will be extremely good if I find the help.

Comment: The order in which you add libraries with the `-l` option is relevant. Move the `-ly` option last after the source file, so you build like `cc bison.tab.c -ly`.

Comment: So library `liby` contains a default main to be used when no main is provided by the user. That means main must be found _first_ so no main will be extracted from the library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are linking library `liby` (linker option `-ly`).  [The Bison manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Yacc-Library.html#Yacc-Library) has this to say about it:

> The Yacc library contains default implementations of the `yyerror` and
>   `main` functions.

So that's why you have multiple definitions of `main`.  You provide one, and there's one in liby.

Moreover, the docs go on to say that

> **These default implementations are normally not useful**, but POSIX requires them.

(Emphasis added)

**You do not need to link liby** in order to build a program that includes a bison-generated parser, and normally you should not do so.  Instead, provide your own `main()` and your own `yyerror()`, both of which you've already done.

Additionally, you are expected to provide a *definition* of `yyin`, not just a declaration, whether you link liby or not.  To do so, remove the `extern` keyword from the declaration of `yyin` in your grammar file.

Your grammar is not complete (there are no rules at all) and the `%name` directive is not documented and is not recognized by my Bison, but if I add a dummy rule and comment out the `%name`, in conjunction with the other changes discussed, then `bison` generates a C source file for me that can be successfully compiled to an executable (without liby).

Comment: And, if you do link the library, put the library after the object (or source) files in the command line (which is what you should do with libraries in general): `cc bison.tab.c -ly` — that too would fix the problem.